# `never` type is assignable to `number`?

Tags: typescript

I am writing some documentation about TypeScript and I'm talking about the possible usefulness of the `never` keyword, one being exhaustive checking, [as described here:](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/never#use-case-exhaustive-checks)

I have some code like this:

```
type PossibleStrings = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'chaz'; 


function fail() : never {
    throw new Error("This endpoint should never be reached");
}

function usesString(value: PossibleStrings) : number {
    if (value === 'foo') {
        return 1
    }; 

    if (value === 'bar') {
        return 2
    }; 

    return fail();
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGVgCdkB2A5glALxQDkAZnHJVAD5WoCGuDzlAxgBasAvSgG4oAKAnUArgW7BkcAlGqtk6ABQBKKAC4oBCADcIuKAG8xUK1GC9ccAO76ITgKK57udQCIAKr2RSCAIAEzA4QmAoBF44KXQQ52NTVGhcCFY+CBDvTWExAF9JGTkFJSkECAQcfGJ1Q1Z0KQg9eCQ0TBrCEm09AikAW1TTC2soZGooesbm8jIKGjpKbVGx63TgKVwlAEZLawLRCTGJqYam6HmFtg4V-bWoDa2lACZ7qEPxd6ft5VUNPKFIA)

Now I would expect that this would be giving an error, as you shouldn't be able to return the `never` type from this function.

And actually if we just strip this down, it seems like the function is a-ok with returning a never type:

```
type PossibleStrings = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'chaz'; 


function fail() : never {
    throw new Error("This endpoint should never be reached");
}

function usesString(value: PossibleStrings) : number {
  return fail();
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGVgCdkB2A5glALxQDkAZnHJVAD5WoCGuDzlAxgBasAvSgG4oAKAnUArgW7BkcAlGqtk6ABQBKKAC4oBCADcIuKAG8xUK1GC9ccAO76ITgKK57udQCIAKr2RSCAIAEzA4QmAoBF44KXQQ52NTVGhcCFY+CBDvTWExAF9JGTkFJSkECAQcfGJ1Q1Z0KQg9eCQ0TBrCEm09AikAW1TTCyt04ClcJRU1LXyCoA)

Seems... broken. What's going on here?

Edit: Answer is [right in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never):

> *The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type;* however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself). Even any isn’t assignable to never.

Is there a way to change that behaviour, or otherwise get this code to behave how I want? ie. I want the `return fail()` to only be valid if all other branches are exhausted.

Comment: I think the edit changes the question rather markedly. But what do you mean by *"I want the return fail() to only be valid if all other branches are exhausted."* Isn't that what the code does?

Comment: Side note: You don't put `;` after the blocks attached to control structures. You *do* put them after `return` statements (unless you're intentionally relying on automatic semicolon insertion, which your code doesn't otherwise seem to be). So `if (value === 'foo') { return 1 };` should be `if (value === 'foo') { return 1; }`.

Comment: It does look like Basarat's documentation is wrong here. I've created a PR to update.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Ah - just saw your comment. Ok thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to rather than relying on the return type of the fail function to cause compile time errors, you use the parameters of the fail function.

```
type PossibleStrings = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'chaz'; 


function fail(value: never) : never {
    throw new Error("This endpoint should never be reached");
}

function usesString(value: PossibleStrings) : number {
    if (value === 'foo') {
        return 1
    } 

    if (value === 'bar') {
        return 2
    }

    return fail(value); //Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)

}
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGVgCdkB2A5glALxQDkAZnHJVAD5WoCGuDzlAxgBasAvSgG4oAKAnUArgW7BkcAlGqtk6ABQA3VuikQAXFAIRNEXAEooh46dxQA3mKjOowXrjgB3IxG8BRXA9cdQAiABVeZFIIAgATMDhCYCgEXjgpdFifWyhUaFwIVj4IWJDzYTEAX0kZOQUlKQQIBBx8Yi0dPUN4JDRMVsISS2spAFs8u0cXKGRqKA7daDJlqlp6SynplwLgKVwlAEYnF0rxY+dZ+e1F8hXKNg4N862dvaUAJmfq59f95VUNNc9OUoAB6UEAQVwRDGMWScDmoEgVAQeEGDCiRjgyVYvSIBFYGGgwDgUDA7FYowgwDMUARrnA0EoNjMlAAdOp3gBmAAsAFZzBJKkA)

When the possible values are exhaustively checked, this no longer causes a compile time error.